# Can't deploy on IIS - Unauthorized error

Tags: iis, deployment, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7, unauthorized

I deployed an application on IIS a couple weeks ago, and now when I'm trying to update it it shows me an error:

> Connected to the remote computer ... using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permission to access the site. ... . The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

[image]

When i clicked on publish first it showed me an warning about a certificate that i was using, and I clicked yes to continue, and then when i wrote the Username and Password suddenly stopped while showing me this error.

Why is this happening> Thought I'm using the same user as i published a couple weeks ago.

Comment: Did you add a certificate to your server recently?  WHen I made my sites HTTPS something similar to this happened to me.

Comment: @dave317 sorry the problem was that someone has changed the password without announcement.